# My wordpress search form not showing results

Tags: wordpress, forms, search

The problem is that [My WP site](http://www.gonpires.com/laclabiche/)'s search form is only showing the search results whenever a page is asked, but If any other text on any page, such as 'lorem ipsum' is used on the search box, after executing the form, no results are displayed.(if you enter 'living' or 'business' it gets you an answer, but if your input is any random text like 'lorem' nothing happens).

I believe this is because the search form is looking for text in the Wordpress theme only, and not looking for text inside the templates.php included in each page.

How can I fix the search form to search for everything, so that when I put 'lorem ipsum' on the form and press enter, results show me the pages where 'lorem ipsum' is.

Answer (score 0):

Different WordPress Themes feature different template files. Some include a search.php template file. This is not a Search Page, it is merely a template that displays the search results.

Read this page.

> http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Search_Page

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've read the codex, I do have both search.php and searchform.php. The template that displays the search result was custom built from cero by me, and I added a div containig the search loop. But as I mentioned on the description it only shows the pages name results, and I really really need it to work as a complete search form showing any text available that matches the input added to the search box...